# Writing an invention

Tags: theory, composition, counterpoint

I am an amateur piano player without systematic musical education. I love listening to and playing 18th-century contrapuntal music especially written by JS Bach. Recently I decided to deepen my theoretical knowledge of this style and started to read some literature. As an exercise I tried to write a simple two-part invention myself. Here is the result (pdf+mp3): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12KL7wU7TYbRZ4rZKUk3OdjX7_yhHsy8Y?usp=sharing

I kindly ask you to assess whether this fits the musical style, what mistakes I made and what should be improved. Thank you very much in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: Hi Rex. Welcome to the site. The main site steers clear of the kind of assessment and feedback you're looking for, but the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) encourages it. Please re-post this question there. I believe you'll find the kind of comments you're looking for.